# How to hide html Elements display on ckeditor

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

Halo guys. i have php project use CI (CodeIgniter) Framework. i have to use CKeditor for my textarea. im using ckeditor5-build-classic-11.0.1, the latest CKEDITOR. everything is fine until i want to edit some article.

[image]

the data that insert into table is this

```
<p><em><strong>test test test</strong></em></p>
```

how do i remove tha element when display it into ckeditor?

and here is my CI code for display it

```
<?php
$options = array(
    'class' => 'ckeditor',
    'id' => 'content',
    'name' => 'content',
    'value' => isset($data['content']) ? set_value('content', $data['content']) : set_value('content'),
    'rows'  => '10',
    'required' => 'required',
);
echo form_textarea($options);
echo form_error('content');
?>
```

please advice

Answer (score 0):

Try decoding your data using the below code and use that output in your editor body.

`$data["content"] = html_entity_decode($data["content"]);`